# Browsers and HTTP 1.1 Peristent Connections

Tags: html, http

I understand the value of HTTP/1.1 persistent connections: secondary resources such as CSS/Javascript/Image files can be fetched by a browser in a single connection.

What I don't understand is how the HTTP protocol indicates when a persistent connection should be closed. Is it up to the client or server to end a session?

It would seem that the client would be in a better position to know when the session is "over", since the client is presumably parsing the main HTML resource, and identifying various sub-resources (javascript/css/images, etc.)  When the client is finished parsing and has identified the last "sub-resource", it could send a "Connection: Close" to the server.  However, in practice, using the Firefox HTTP Live-headers plug-in demonstrates that this, in fact, does not happen.

So how does the HTTP/1.1 protocol indicate that there is nothing more to download, and the session should terminate?

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC 2616, Section 8](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html):

### Section 8.1.2 Overall Operation

(emphasis mine)

> Persistent connections provide a mechanism by which a client and a server can signal the close of a TCP connection. **This signaling takes place using the Connection header field** (section [14.10](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.10)). Once a close has been signaled, the client MUST NOT send any more requests on that connection.

### Section 8.1.4 Practical Considerations

> When a client or server wishes to time-out it SHOULD issue a graceful close on the transport connection. Clients and servers SHOULD both constantly watch for the other side of the transport close, and respond to it as appropriate. If a client or server does not detect the other side's close promptly it could cause unnecessary resource drain on the network.

**Note that "SHOULD" in an RFC is not the same as "MUST" - there is no obligation for the client to send a `close` header.** Continuing in Section 8.1.4 (emphasis mine):

> This means that **clients, servers, and proxies MUST be able to recover from asynchronous close events.** Client software SHOULD reopen the transport connection and retransmit the aborted sequence of requests without user interaction so long as the request sequence is idempotent (see section 9.1.2). Non-idempotent methods or sequences MUST NOT be automatically retried, although user agents MAY offer a human operator the choice of retrying the request(s). Confirmation by user-agent software with semantic understanding of the application MAY substitute for user confirmation. The automatic retry SHOULD NOT be repeated if the second sequence of requests fails.

### In practice:

The server just closes the connection **after a preset timeout** after the client's last request by sending a `Connection: close` header and the client side just deals with it.